# Using semicolon and comma in JTextField for search

Tags: java, regex, search, actionlistener, jtextfield

do you have an idea why there are no search results when I use an comma or semicolon in my search bar?
I really get crazy...

Thanks ;-)

```
// Create searchbar
    searchBar = new JTextField(15);
    searchButton.setVisible(false);
// Add to panel
    panel.add(searchBar);
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(searchButton);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

...
...
...

// Integrate ActionListener for textfilter
    searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             String text = searchBar.getText();


            if (text.length() == 0) {
                tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));


            }
        }

    });![Panel with search box][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma and semicolon are used like metacharacters or escape sequences.
Try to use `quote()` method to escape them:

```
tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(text)));
```

Comment: `"(?i)" + Pattern.quote(text)`?